# componentDidMount not called when Route with a different param is called

Tags: reactjs, redux

i'm rendering "Details" component in a callback in my UsersListContainer like this:

```
class UsersListContainer extends Component {
  goToUserById(id) {
    if (!id) { return false; }
    this.props.history.push(`/users/${id}`);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <UserList
      goToUser={(id) => this.goToUserById(id)}/>
    );
  }
}
```

My "Details" container:

```
class UserDetailsContainer extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getUserDetails(this.props.match.params.id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <UserDetails user={this.props.selectedUser}/>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    getUserDetails: id => dispatch(getUser(id))
  };
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  selectedUser: state.user.selectedUser
});
```

And in my presentational "User" component I display a set of data from redux store like this:

```
class UserDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: this.props.user.name,
      address: this.props.user.name,
      workingHours: this.props.user.workingHours,
      phone: this.props.user.phone
    };
  }
```

I'm not displaying component props directly and I use state because they are meant to be edited. This works, but the problem is that all these props are not updating simultaneously with component load which means when I select user for the first time it displays the right info, then I switch back to "/users" to choose another, and his props remain the same as props of the previous user. I tried componentWillUnmount to clear the data but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this by using lodash lib
in my presentational component I compare if objects are equal

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      address: ""
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    _.isEqual(this.props.user, nextProps.user) ? (
      this.setState({
        name: this.props.user.name,
        address: this.props.user.address
      })
    ) : (
      this.setState({
        name: nextProps.user.name,
        address: nextProps.user.address,
      })
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you implement a Route like `/users/:id`, and if you change the id to something else, the entire component is not re-mounted and hence the `componentDidMount` is not called, rather only the props change and hence you need to implement `componentWillReceiveProps` function also

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getUserDetails(this.props.match.params.id);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(this.props.match.params.id !== nextProps.match.params.id) {
        this.props.getUserDetails(nextProps.match.params.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for a quick reply but it still loads previous data, for example from the start, I select a user and blank details are rendered, but when I re-select it, it works. then next user is rendered with props of a previous and so on

Comment: you are assigning props to state in UserDetails component in constructor, but they are not initially available and hence it doesn't still work, so either you need to make use of props isntead of state or implement componentWillReceiveProps in UserDetails component as well