# React-router dynamic route with dynamic action

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

Understand that you can create dynamic routes with:

`<Route path="/:category" component={PostsContainer} />`

```
class PostsContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    <p>{this.props.match.params.category}</p>
  }
}
```

So my question is how can I add dynamic route to actions with api call to dispatch?

I would like to do something like when in category a, send a api call to category a, then dispatch... while in category b send a api call to category b, then dispatch...

```
export const getPostsAction = (match) => (dispatch) => {
  getPosts(category).then((posts) => {
    dispatch({
      type: postsConst.GET_ALL_POSTS_SUCCESS,
      posts,
    });
  });
};
```

problem is I can't use componentDidMount with this.props.getPostsAction(category), it only happen one time, even I click around to different /categories... or maybe I should be updating from componentWillRecieveProps, but I am not really sure whats the best way...

Comment: How is API call to category A different from category B

Comment: Can you give an example of the type of action you are wanting to dispatch? What is dynamic about it?

Comment: added the action. so getPosts will have something like /api/category/${category}

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47787571/props-are-not-updating-with-component-load-react-redux/47787662#47787662

Comment: You know I put this in my answer half an hour ago :)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: To address your edit - Dispatch your action in `componentWillReceiveProps` anytime `this.props.match.params.category !== nextProps.match.params.category`.

This should work; provided `postsConst` is defined.

```
export const getPostsAction = (match) => (dispatch) => {
    return getPosts(`/api/category/${match.params.category}`).then(posts => {
        dispatch({
            type: postsConst.GET_ALL_POSTS_SUCCESS,
            posts,
        });
    });
};
```

You can also dispatch an action before the return statement so that your application knows it is currently fetching data. Something like: `dispatch({type: "IS_FETCHING_POSTS"})` and of course you would need a reducer for that action.

If you need more information on async actions in redux, take a look at the [Async Actions Documentation](https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html).

Here is an example provided in the documentation:

```
export function fetchPosts(subreddit) {
  // Thunk middleware knows how to handle functions.
  // It passes the dispatch method as an argument to the function,
  // thus making it able to dispatch actions itself.

  return function (dispatch) {
    // First dispatch: the app state is updated to inform
    // that the API call is starting.

    dispatch(requestPosts(subreddit))

    // The function called by the thunk middleware can return a value,
    // that is passed on as the return value of the dispatch method.

    // In this case, we return a promise to wait for.
    // This is not required by thunk middleware, but it is convenient for us.

    return fetch(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${subreddit}.json`)
      .then(
        response => response.json(),
        // Do not use catch, because that will also catch
        // any errors in the dispatch and resulting render,
        // causing a loop of 'Unexpected batch number' errors.
        // https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6895
        error => console.log('An error occurred.', error)
      )
      .then(json =>
        // We can dispatch many times!
        // Here, we update the app state with the results of the API call.

        dispatch(receivePosts(subreddit, json))
      )
  }
}
```